# WPF, C# File Archiving

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF Application creates several files with each instance of its use. These files can be reused. As the user continues to use it, I want to ensure that the files get archived over time and the user doesn't find the folder with hundreds of files after a while. What can I do for this?

Comment: Can you give us a few more specifics? Do the files become non-used after a certain time frame? If a file has been archived and needs to be accessed, should it just be regenerated?

Comment: The files can be assumed non-used after a month. If it needs to be accessed after its been archived it just has to be regenerated

Comment: So you could probably just run something on app startup (if your app gets restarted very often) that checks for files older than a month and dumps them into a folder and zips the folder. I've used SharpZipLib, so I'll upvote that.

Answer (score 1):

By archiving - do you mean that you want to compress the files to a zip file or similiar?

If that is the case - you could use Sharp Zip Lib.

see:

http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/c-using-sharp-zip-lib-to-compress-files-SID586.aspx

With that it should be straight forward to compress your older files to an archivedfiles.zip